# WCF service in Windows 10 app

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, uwp

I created a WCF service that retrieves data from a database and displays the information.

First question: When I submit the app to the store, does the WCF service get bundled with app, how does that work?

Second question: I noticed when the service is running, IIS is also running on my system, so what happens if a user doesn't have IIS or what happens when it runs on a windows phone.

Lastly, I noticed when IIS isn't running and I open the app, the app crashes, why does it do so, shouldn't it be able to start the service?

Please I am not an expert on this, and this is my first time using a WCF service, so be patient with me and give as much detail as possible.

Thanks.

WCF service:

```
namespace CustomerService
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
// NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOD;Initial Catalog=DB2;User ID=sa;Password=*********");
    public Customer getCustomer()
    {
        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string strSql = "SELECT * FROM Table_1";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, sqlCon);
            sqlDa.Fill(ds);

            Customer objCus = new Customer();
            objCus.Age = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
            objCus.Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
            return objCus;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }

    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

}

```
namespace CustomerService
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
    [OperationContract]
    Customer getCustomer();
}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    int age;
    string name;

    [DataMember]
    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

}

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Customer g = await obj.getCustomerAsync();
        ageTB.Text = g.Age.ToString();
        nameTB.Text = g.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF Services are meant to be backend services. This means that it is not shipped with the app, but it is hosted somewhere else.

So:
Question1: No, it is not bundled to the app, you have to take care about the hosting

Question2: Visual Studio starts an IIS for you, but in production it should be hosted on a server. A Windows Phone app typically connects to it via the internet. One hosting option would be Azure…

Question3: If the service is not available the app should deal with it… (For example a try catch in the  Button_Click event handler would do the work..)